# how can i add min and max annotation for double numbers in Json generator?

Tags: java, json, code-generation

I am trying to write a json code generator (to java) which can force min and max numbers with annotation ( like DecimalMin and DecimalMax in jakarta validation).
there is some code for that ? any package ?

Comment: did you try something?